# mybatis insert nested pojo with lists

Tags: java, spring-boot, mybatis

I have nested pojos where i am inserting this information in to database. I am using mybatis for my DB insertions.

```
public class Student {

    private List<Bike> bikes;
    private long lastInsertId;

    //getters and setters
}

public class Bike {
   private String name;
   private List<Key> bikeKeys;

   //getters and setters
}

public class Key {

   private String id;
   private String name;

   //getters and setters
}
```

After this, in mybatis mapper file i am inserting as below which is not working.

```
<insert id="insertDetails" parameterType="com.media.domain.Student">
    <foreach item="bike" index="index" collection="bikes">
       <foreach item="bkItem" index="index" collection="bikeKeys">
        INSERT INTO mapping(key,id,name,keyname) VALUES
        (#{lastInsertId, jdbcType=INTEGER}, #{bkItem.id, jdbcType=VARCHAR}, #{bike.name, jdbcType=VARCHAR}, #{bkItem.name, jdbcType=VARCHAR});
       </foreach>
    </foreach>
</insert>
```

I am getting below error for the above insert statement.

```
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: There is no getter for property named 'bikeKeys' in 'class com.media.domain.Student'
```

Can i get some help?
Thanks.

Comment: What is your getter method for bikeKeys ?

Comment: `public List<Key> getBikeKeys() {
        return bikeKeys;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Working solution for me

```
<insert id="insertDetails" parameterType="com.media.domain.Student">
<foreach item="bike" index="index" collection="bikes">
   <foreach item="bkItem" index="index" collection="bike.bikeKeys">
    INSERT INTO mapping(key,id,name,keyname) VALUES
    (#{lastInsertId, jdbcType=INTEGER}, #{bkItem.id, jdbcType=VARCHAR}, #{bike.name, jdbcType=VARCHAR}, #{bkItem.name, jdbcType=VARCHAR});
   </foreach>
</foreach>
```